# Function Downcasting in UnityScript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I actually posted this on the Unity forums, but none of my language-related questions ever seem to get answered there. So, let's say I have a function defined as so in Unity Script:

```
function GetSomething : SomeClass
{
   return new SomeClass();
}
```

Where SomeClass is some class defined elsewhere. Now, I have a variable, theFunction, of type Function, and I want to make sure that it returns something, anything. So what I do is the following:

```
// theFunction is set to GetSomething somewhere else in the program.
var functionThatReturnsSomething = theFunction as function() : Object;

if (functionThatReturnsSomething != null)
//... call it and do stuff with the returned value.
```

Now unfortunately, in the above code functionThatReturnsSomething will be null. For it not to be null, I have to be more specific and cast to function() : SomeClass OR just override the function definition to return an Object as so:

```
function GetSomething : Object
{
   return new SomeClass();
}
```

This is very annoying because its easy to forget to do :Object (especially since if you leave it out it will correctly infer it to be of return type SomeClass), and the result is not an error, but rather a very subtle bug since the cast fails. Is there any way to get the behavior I want, which is for it to properly downcast to function() : Object, the same way I can downcast normal objects?

Comment: erm.. Why don't you just call the function by name? What's the point in having an object of itself?

Comment: My program isn't literally doing the above, this is a situation that arrises from a class that can hold a callback. The callback is of type Function, and the user of the API can choose to provide a callback that either returns a value (and that value gets used), or one that returns void. I use the typecast to check which of the situations I am in.

Comment: So I agree, why make the object? why not just set and get that one piece of data?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is you forgot the parenthesis after the function name when you declare it. If i put everything into the following script, attach it to an object and run it then i get access to the function with no problems.

```
#pragma strict

import System.Collections.Generic;

function Start ()
{
    // theFunction is set to GetSomething somewhere else in the program.
    var functionThatReturnsSomething = GetSomething as function() : Object;

    if (functionThatReturnsSomething != null)
    {
        //... call it and do stuff with the returned value.
        Debug.Log(functionThatReturnsSomething);
    }
    else Debug.Log("null");
}

function GetSomething() : List.<int>
{
    return new List.<int>();
}
```